# Microsoft Logging Single Line

Tags: c#, logging, microsoft.extensions.logging

Can someone recommend how to convert Microsoft Logging stdout into single line and eliminate the class method

Default Logger Output

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/todo/0

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController.GetById (TodoApi) with arguments (0) - ModelState is Valid
```

What I want

```
info: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/todo/0

info: Executing action method TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController.GetById (TodoApi) with arguments (0) - ModelState is Valid
```

Comment: How are you logging it?  What "class method" are you referring to?  All methods are in classes in C#.

Comment: What is *"Microsoft Logging"*?

Comment: We are using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. The "class" I am referring to is the origin of the log request, i.e. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]

Answer (score 1):

*Time flies ;-)*

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.console.simpleconsoleformatteroptions.singleline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

This is what I use currently:

```
  services.AddLogging(options =>
            {
                options.AddSimpleConsole(c =>
                {
                    c.TimestampFormat = "[yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss] ";
                    c.UseUtcTimestamp = true;
                    c.SingleLine = true; // Only this line is needed for this question
                });
            });
```